# What is the largest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of four pentagonal numbers?

Tags: number-theory

By Fermat's polygonal number theorem, every number can be written as the sum of five pentagonal numbers. The largest integer I've been able to find that can't be represented as the sum of four pentagonal numbers was 21 (searched up to 21)(I am not good enough at coding to code this up). What is the largest such number?

Comment: $89$.  See [this](http://oeis.org/A133929).  Note:  I am not confident that this has been proven, just that it has been conjectured and backed up numerically.  Similarly, it is conjectured that there are only $210$ natural numbers that need more than $3$.  See [this](http://oeis.org/search?q=4%2C+8%2C+9%2C+16%2C+19%2C+20%2C+21%2C+26%2C+30%2C+31%2C+33%2C+38%2C+42%2C+43%2C+50%2C+54&sort=&language=&go=Search).  And [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PentagonalNumber.html#:~:text=There%20are%20six%20positive%20integers,and%2089%20(OEIS%20A133929).) for a general discussion.

Comment: Sure there is a largest number for which we need five pentagonal numbers ?

Comment: FYI, a list of pentagonal numbers is at https://oeis.org/A000326

Comment: @lulu: You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Dan that is the best way to gain reputation

Comment: Just to say:  I'm not a fan of link only answers.  I'm sure someone here is clear as to the status of $89$...I am under the impression that the problem was solved, but a quick search didn't turn up the proof.  I'd be curious to know if that was fully settled or not.